# how to escape input but save unescaped into the database

Tags: php, mysql, escaping

It is said that in order to prevent from SQL injection one should filter the input data eg. with addslashes or mysql_real_escape_string depending on used connection modules

However, data escaped with addslashes is being saved into the database WITH the slashes, so a user surname would save as O\'Reilly instead O'Reilly. The one needs to use stripslashes to display it correctly.

So how do I use addslashes and save into the database without slashes? Is it actually the way it should be done?

Comment: It looks like you escape string twice( maybe you are using PDO and  `mysql_real_escape_string` at the same time).

Comment: yes, I'm using PDO and I addslashes before. How exactly PDO escapes characters on its own?

Comment: If you use PDO, and assign parameters with `bindParam`/`bindValue`, you don't need to worry about escaping, PDO will do it for you

Comment: so, when using PDO basically, I could go with $_POST["var"] and pass it direcly into bindParam/bindValue, correct? And when using mysql_connect, I have to put $_POST through mysql_real_escape_string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You DONT use `addslashes` you use the appropriate DB specific escaping function like `mysql_real_escape_string`.

if you are using PDO then using a prepared statement will escape the variables as part of binding process. In this case all you need to do is something like:

```
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $name);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO your_table (col1, col2,col3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)');
$stmt->execute(array('value 1', 'value 2', 'value 3');
```

OR for extra readability and esier reuse you can use named params:

```
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $name);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO your_table (col1, col2,col3) VALUES (:col1, :col2, :col3)');
$stmt->execute(array(':col1' =>'value 1', ':col2' =>'value 2', ':col3' =>'value 3');
```

Comment: ok... you guys contradict yourselves a bit... a1ex07 says bindParam escapes data, you say that prepare escapes data.

Comment: There are multiple ways to bind paramters to a statement... you can do it with bindParam, or you can do it as i have done here, or you can even use `PDO::quote` for instances where you cant use a prepared statement. There is more than one way to skin a cat but they will both do the same thing essentially. Which one you use depends what/how you need to code the functionality. [Check out this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) for the basics.

Answer (score 0):

`addslashes` is supposed to be a one-size-fits-all escaping mechanism. If you MySQL-escape an `addslash`-escaped strings, of course the value including the `addslash` slashes will be saved to the database. Use either or, not both.

Having said that, **don't use `addslashes`**. It serves no real purpose. Use the specific escaping mechanism for the appropriate situation. I.e., only use `mysql_real_escape_string`. Or prepared statements, which avoids the whole escaping mess to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

If you use prepared statements (via PDO or the mysqli library, for instance,) you don't need to escape or filter anything.